# Dynamic table column update by id, done right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am kinda new to Ajax/Json so I would like to know if the following is at least near to the best practice. The goal is to update specific columns (in this case quantity and price) of a table every x seconds.

I got a HTML table defined like this:

```
<table id="#edition_table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a href="?card=12345">Lightning Bolt</a></td>
        [...]
        <td class="qty">2</td>
        <td class="price">$4.99</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a href="?card=23456">Fireball</a></td>
        [...]
        <td class="qty">0</td>
        <td class="price">$0.07</td>
    <tr>
    [...]
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And a JS function defined like this:

```
function edition_update(edition)
{
    var table_rows = $('#edition_table').find('tbody tr td.name a');

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', url: 'ajax_edition_update.php', data: { edition : edition }, dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json_rows)
    {
          var new_qty, new_price;

          table_rows.each(function(index) {
                var td_id = $(this).attr('href').replace('?card=', '');

                for (i in json_rows) {
                    if (json_rows[i].card_id == td_id)
                    {
                        new_qty = json_rows[i].qty;
                        new_price = json_rows[i].low_price;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                var parent_tr = $(this).parent().parent();

                parent_tr.find('td.qty').text(new_qty);
                parent_tr.find('td.price').text(!isNaN(new_price) ? '$' + new_price : new_price);
          });
    }
    });

    setTimeout(edition_update, 30000, edition);
}
```

The PHP file returns a JSON including card_id, qty and low_price.

This does work fine. I guess I could set up a `data-id=[card_id]` on the class=name td to get rid of the .replace, but that kinda blows up the html footprint as the id is already present.

The real question is whether any performance improvements (especially regarding the two loops) are possible or necessary? The target number of rows per table is arround 500 and the content and order is totally dynamic/unpredictable, of course.

Comment: Maybe, this should be posted at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - Nevertheless, are you able to change the returned JSON? To something like `{"card12345": {"qty": 1, "low_price": 2}, "card23456": {"qty": 2, "low_price": 3}}`? With this you would be able to get the data for a card without the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, did not know about codereview, certainly more suitable there. Do you have a link for the direct lookup method you are refering to ?

Comment: Something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akZWA/)